# Generate UUID based on given parameters?

Tags: scala

Is there any way to generate uuid based on parameters?
I have 3 parameters of types: Date, Int & Int
I want to generate UUID based on three of them, such that every time for same 3 I will get the same UUID.

Comment: Why don't you simply hash them together? A UUID is normally random each time it's generated.

Comment: Is there a way to create uuid based on hashed value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A UUID has 128 bits, so if you're talking about a `java.util.Date` which stores a 64-bit timestamp (`Long`), and two 32-bit `Int`s, then you *can* make a unique UUID for each combination.

`java.util.UUID` has a constructor that accepts two `Long`s (64-bit). The `Date` can be one of them, and the two 32-bit `Int`s can be combined into one by bit-shifting the first by 31 to the left (1 bit is for the sign), and adding the second.

```
import java.util.{ Date, UUID }

def generate(date: Date, a: Int, b: Int): UUID =
    new UUID(date.getTime, a.toLong << 31 + b.toLong)

scala> val d = new Date()
d: java.util.Date = Wed Mar 02 11:22:52 EST 2016

scala> generate(d, 23, 43532)
res23: java.util.UUID = 00000153-3823-9fa6-0000-000b8000aa0c
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about `java.util.UUID` (I suppose Scala uses this Java object under the hood) it's possible to create UUID on a base of some array of bytes with `nameUUIDFromBytes(byte[] name)`. So what you need is to create this array from your Date, Int & Int.